# Run Python Multiprocessing of same function with multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a function say:

```
 Fun1(a,b):
   return a*b
```

I want to call Fun1, multiple times with different values of a and b.
Need to use multiprocessing as Fun1 is an called millions of time in the

Comment: Have you checked `ProcessPollExecutor` with `map` ?

Comment: Can you show me an example? can't seem to get with using 2 different arguments for the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def fun1(a, b):
    return a * b

# if __name__ == '__main__': is required for platforms that do not
# support fork(), such as Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 6]
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers = 3) as executor:
        results = executor.map(fun1, a, b)
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

```
4
10
18
```